# Downloading files from a pipe with wget? Cannot write to - (broken pipe) error

Tags: pipe, wget

I'm attempting to download my website using wget.

I have a `sitemap.xml` that contains the links to every page on my site.  This is the download source.

Here's my command:

```
wget --verbose http://example.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "http://example.com/[^<]+" | wget --verbose -i -
```

This will download every page, but the problem is that only the HTML is downloaded-- none of the images, CSS, or anything else.

So, based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/373075), I wanted to add the options `-E -H -k -p`:

> -E: Append .html to the file name if it is an HTML file but doesn't end in .html or similar
> -H: Download files from other hosts, too
> -k: After downloading convert any link in it so they point to the downloaded files
> -p: Download anything the page needs for proper offline viewing

However, when I modify my command

```
wget --verbose http://example.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "http://example.com/[^<]+" | wget --verbose -i -E -H -k -p -
```

Then I get an error:

> **Cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe).**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GNU `wget` if you use `-i` it should be immediately followed by filename (or `-` meaning standard input), this

```
wget --verbose -i -
```

is ok, but here

```
wget --verbose -i -E -H -k -p -
```

there is not filename after `-i`, but some other options, please try following

```
wget --verbose -E -H -k -p -i -
```

then write if it did work for you. When you use [`wget`'s man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) take care if option should or must not be followed by parameter, for example `-i` should and thus does appear as

> **-i** *file*

whilst e.g. v (be verbose) must not and thus does appear just as

> **-v**

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
apt install gnupg
```

Should fix the issue.